# Google sheets data comparison

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to make a formula that will compare if the order is canceled (A:B), then it will be displayed along with the material in the final sheet (C:D) - I don't know how to go about it, does anyone have any idea?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG4dT.png]

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2:E,{B2:B,A2:A},2,0)))
```

[image]

*(please adjust formula according to your ranges and locale)*

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)